# HierarchicalDataTemplate what is it supposed to do?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Basically i have a eeview that has a bunch of objects in it and the treeview needs to bind the same properties.

here is the code im using and it doesnt seem to work

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Drives}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                                </TreeViewItem>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Basically when i get to the third level of treeview items i just get the Namespace+ObjectName.
Isnt the DataTemplate supposed to flow on and on ?

Comment: have you tried to remove the stackpanel?

Comment: You don't need to nest `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s like this. A single one would do assuming that the `ItemsSource` is `Folders` in each item in the `TreeView`. Further, check the output window for any binding errors.

Comment: Im getting no binding errors. the binds are all working however the templates are not

Comment: Please post your view model code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More like this

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Drives}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: using this code i get one level of the treeview templated (Base level) and no others each treeview item in the tree needs to be binded to the property Folders

Comment: Interesting because I get all levels.  Do you want me to send you the whole repo code?